How to synchronize changes from a source repo to a destination repo triggered from a push to the source main except some files
I want to synchronize changes from a source repository to a destination repository whenever there is a push to the main branch of the source repository. However, I do not want to sync changes to the main.py file. I have created a file called workflow.yml in the source repo that includes the code attached below.
I have reviewed GitHub actions push to remote repo which is quite close but not the same one.
I have created repository secrets named PAT on my source repo where I pasted my personal access token (I created it by going into the developer settings of my account).
My problem is about the file that I want it not to be updated. If I remove the following line git checkout HEAD^ main.py, when I make a push request to the source repo, the action runs successfully and it syncs all the changes I made. I need git ignore somehow but I am not sure how to apply in this condition. I think if I create .gitignore file, it may create problems when I push the commits to the source repo. If I clone my source repo, make changes, commit and push them, .gitignore will not let my main.py be updated right?
I have added the following line if: github.repository == 'myname/source_repo so that the action does not run on the destination repo. Ideally, I would like not to sync workflow.yml to the destination repo (and delete it once). Therefore, I would like not to sync both main.py and workflow.yml files.
name: Sync Repos

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    if: github.repository == 'myname/source_repo'

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure Git
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "myname@outlook.com"
          git config --global user.name "myname"
          git config --global credential.helper store

      - name: Clone destination repository
        run: |
          echo "https://${{ secrets.PAT }}@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
          git clone https://${{ secrets.PAT }}@github.com/myname/sync_project.git
          cd sync_project
          git remote add source https://${{ secrets.PAT }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git
          git fetch source
          git checkout -b temp-branch source/main
          git checkout main

          # Restore the main.py file from the temp-branch
          git checkout HEAD^ main.py
          
          git merge temp-branch --allow-unrelated-histories
          git push origin main
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}

I tried running git checkout HEAD^ main.py in my workflow in order to revert main.py to its state in the previous commit (not to sync it to the destination repo) but it did ot work out. I tried git restore --source=HEAD@{1} -- main.py .github/workflows/workflow.yml but it did not work either. I did not create a .gitignore file that would contain main.py for the reason I mentioned above.

Considering that the source repo is read only, add .gitignore to the destination repo only.

Thanks for the answer but it did not work out. main.py at the repo updated when I pushed changes to the source repo.
